# Protractor: non-angular login page is reloading

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm testing an angular page but before I have to log in on non-angular page which goes also to non-angular one. When I try to run my test and input username and password the page is reloading.

In my conf file I have ignoreSynchronization set on true, I also tried to put it in beforeEach and AfterEach but it didn't help.
The error is "Failed: Wait timed out after .... s".

Comment: Do you have a `browser.wait()` in your code .. Can you paste the code snippet where you are seeing the error

Comment: How does your conf.js look like. Can you post its contents

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add below to your conf.js file and verify again:

```
  onPrepare: function() {          
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  }
```